# Combining filters in django

Tags: python, django, filtering

I am using django_filters and I have a little problem with combining it each other.

What do I have? Basic filters, for example:

```
class BasicFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = []


class TimeFilter(BasicFilter):
    created = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
        help_text='Date from - to', label='Time'
    )
    class Meta(BasicFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['created']


class AgentFilter(BasicFilter):
    agent = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=AgentClass.objects.all(), help_text=''
    )
    class Meta(BasicFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['agent']


class SomethingElseFilter(BasicFilter):
    something = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=SomethingElse.objects.all(), help_text=''
    )
    class Meta(BasicFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['something']
```

The user will decide which filters he wants, e.g. He will choose TimeFilter and AgentFilter, and I need to connect this basic filters to one ConnectedFilter. 
Then I handle it in my views, e.g.

```
class MyView(ListView):
model = myModel
template_name = "filters.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    qs=MyModel.objects.all()
    try:
        self.connected_filter = ConnectedFilter(
            self.request.GET, queryset = qs)

        return self.connected_filter
    except:
        return qs


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter_form'] = self.connected_form.as_table()
    return context
```

Or maybe there's some better solution.

Comment: Your solution looks good for me.

Comment: I have no solution :D, this is my idea, but I don't know how can I do this. I don't know how to create this ConnectedFilter

Comment: Why do you need this? You already choose any filters you want to combine in your query parameters.

Comment: I have a model which has 10 fields. And I need to have filter for each fields but sometimes (when I will generate form from this filters) I need 3 filters, sometimes 7. And I need something universaly for this. For example: when I have X = [TimeFilter, AgentFIlter], I want to generate ConnectedFilter which has TimeFilter ang AgentFilter in his fields atribut. When I have X = [AgentFilter] I want to generate ConnectedFilter which has only AgentFilter in his fields.